# Finding the closing stock valuation using a single formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the closing stock valuation in excel. Purchases of Raw material are made during a month & FIFO method is used. At the end of the month i do have the closing stock quantity. I need to find the following:

*a) Closing stock value.*

*b) Average rate i.e. (Closing Stock Value/Quantity).*

I do have 20 different type of raw materials & need to value them. The result i want to achieve is in the attached image.

I have tried it in a more manual way & includes multiple formulas.

[image]

Comment: If you can add a column with the sold quantity, there is a simple way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @ImtiazAhmed i know the closing stock of the quantity & hence need to go backwards tracing my purchases. The screenshot given by you doesn't solve the issue as you have taken the average of all the purchases. In my case, i need to go to the purchase quantity going backwards until my closing stock is exhausted.

Comment: The first case is easy to incorporate, but the second case is the main problem as the stocks remaining may be of last 2, 3 or 4 stocks data and it will be hard to know. But I am trying, will post when done.

Comment: @ImtiazAhmed now you got my point. That's what i have been trying to crack & it has got over my head. I am very thankful for your help. I am eagerly awaiting for your solution.